# Convert string to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: iphone, string, nsstring, location, coordinates

I have an array with NSString's in it.  Some of these are latitude and longitudes and I need to use this with the below code.

The latText and lonText are my strings that I am trying to use as co-ordinates....

```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D pinlocation=mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

    pinlocation.latitude = latText;

    pinlocation.longitude  =lonText;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
pinlocation.latitude = [latText doubleValue];
```